# SQL Encrypt a Column syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, encryption

I tried this example [Column encryption example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

But in this line:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'SQLAuthority'
```

I get that error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = MASTER ]

Comment: Did you mean to say you tried [this example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/)?

Comment: try using a STRONG PASSWORD, Lower case, Upper case, Number and a special character.

Comment: I would highly recommend not using the example password.

Comment: @MuhammedAli Like `w0R&` ?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO  no something like Y0uRaMuPp3T lolll

Comment: @MuhammedAli `Y0uRaMuPp3T` doesn't have a special character.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Y0uRaMuPp3T10O% better now ??

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO jokes aside your a DBA if you dont mind have a look at this pal and suggest something if you can think of any possible solution cheers pal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274485/ssrs-reports-manager-security-configuration

Comment: Tried this password:'Y0uRaMuPp3T10O%' didnt help

Comment: sry for question im new with sql server, may be the reason is that i use sql server compact?

Comment: @aldron69 Im sorry pal I was just having a laugh with FreshPrinceOfSO  I didnt mean to literally use this password, I tried with your password and it worked, sometimes when you dont use a strong password it doesnt create a master key but it seems you recommended password is fine there is something else I am sorry I couldnt  be much help :(

Comment: Judging by the error message, you are probably using SQL Server Compact. CREATE MASTER KEY may not be supported in your product.

Comment: Im new to sql server, i need to use engine database?